# Google Map is coming top left corner only by gmaps4rails 2.0.3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am Using gmaps4rails v2 + rails 4 + ruby 2 + geocoder
I am following standard document from github for gmaps4rails v2
but i am getting google map only at top most left corner,means full map is not coming.
**Gem**
gem 'gmaps4rails'
**View**

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

**javascript pipeline**

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps_google
```

**controller**

```
@users = User.all
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
  marker.lat user.latitude
  marker.lng user.longitude
end
```

**View**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: { Zoom: 10 }, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
});
handler.map.centerOn({ lat: <%=raw @hash[0][:lat] %>, lng: <%=raw @hash[0][:lng] %> })
});
</script>
```

I am Following this document => https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails
Everything is fine but google map is coming only top left corner...
Any suggestions appreciable..
Thanks

Comment: are you trying to position your map in a certain area or something?  from the looks of it, your code is acting as it should be - coming in from the top left corner since you don't have any other styling other than the inline width/height values.

Comment: Yes,i am trying to position my map in a certain area, I have global.css in my project but if i am giveing inline style-sheet it should work first. please suggest me where i am wrong ????

Comment: this is a css issue, I cant help

Comment: Can you give me any clue where i need to change css..

Comment: Your inline styling is just for width and height dimensions.  In no way does it imply any sort of positional reference.  What are you trying to achieve exactly?  I can't really help if you don't outline what your desired results are.

Comment: Everything is fine but map is coming on top left corner only(full map is not coming).the problem is related this **google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");** Any idea????

Comment: If i am giving this at script "$('#map').mouseover(function(){
     google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});" then map is coming on mouse over but by default it is coming on top left most corner only. Any help appreciable.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution to this weird behaviour??

Comment: @siekfried No buddy i did not get the solution :( i stopped working on this. if you get please let me know.